# Need to add a default value in a string inside a method in java

Tags: java

Suppose we have a string BE231231.

I need an output like this : BE0231231

need to append zero at a this fixed location in java inside a method

Comment: What is the code you have written for this ?

Comment: What do you need a mask?? ie the input could be BE1 and the output will be BE0000001?

Answer (score 2):

```
public String appendAtIndex(String base, String toAppend, int index){
    return base.substring(0,index) + toAppend + base.substring(index);
}
```

You can implement the logic for restrictions on index accordingly so that base.substring does not give errors.